# Problem with AJAX calls in Django app while developing google chrome extension

Tags: python, django, ajax, google-chrome-extension, web-development-server

When I am trying to send data to my localhost using the ajax call in popup.js, I am getting an error :
Not Found: /sentiment/
"GET /sentiment/?number=219 HTTP/1.1" 404 1714

Even though I checked the url and it is correct and exists.
This is the snippet of my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({ 
                url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/sentiment/",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{
                    number:newTotal
                },
                crossDomain:true,
                success:function(json)
                {
                    $('#total').text(json.number)
                }
            })
```

and this is my urls.py file in django app :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from DetectHate import views
from django.urls import path,re_path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^sentiment/$', views.sentiment,name="sentiment"),

]
```

and this is my views.py file -

```
import json
from django.http import Http404,HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def sentiment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        var=request.POST.get('number')+5
        data={}
        data['number']=var+5
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Ok. I just had to remove if request.is_ajax condition and it worked. I thought there was problem with url, but 404 was there only because of the else part. The error is in the condition.